# Getting a null data error in forecast function in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm trying to using the forecast function to forecast for an ARIMA model. Here's the code snippet

```
lam<-BoxCox.lambda(data,lower=0,upper = 2,method = "loglik")
arima_model<-auto.arima(data,seasonal = TRUE, allowmean=FALSE, lambda =lam)
arima_forecast<-forecast(arima_model, h=18)
```

The forecast function returns this error

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :
> 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

The arima_model is not a null object.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: check  `class(data)`

Comment: class(data) is numeric. And it's of vector type only

Comment: try str(data). I'm guessing your vector is multiple levels or has some weird naming and you went through a matrix etc.

Comment: Will the forecast() return a null error if the there are large number of small values in the data.In my case the data contains many cases of 0.001. Can it lead to this error? I changed those values to 4, they worked fine.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.